# How to map array of objects to index signature with Array.map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Let's say I've got array of objects:

```
let items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'one'},
    { id: 2, name: 'two'},
    { id: 3, name: 'three'},
];
```

Then I've got result object as [index signature](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures) type:

```
let result: {[key: number]: string};
```

How can I map `items` to `result` using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function?

I can't get the correct syntax for something like this:

```
result = array.map(elem => {[key: elem.id]: elem.name});
```

Comment: `Array.map()` is more suited to modifying the content of an array. You instead want to create/populate another object. Try combining `Object.entries()` and `Array.reduce()`.

Comment: You could use `Array.forEach()` and assign the properties of `result` in each iteration like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQJjYN)

Comment: You forgot to return in your map function.

Comment: @fubar `Array.map()` isn't for modifying the content of an array. It's for creating a new array (with the same number of elements).

Comment: @RoToRa agreed. Poor choice of words on my part. It does create a new array, but it  does so by mapping and modifying the content of the original array.